# What does is mean the property 'setSelectionRange' is missing from type HTMLInputElement

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use the following code to store info about inputs, including the input DOM object itself, in an array.

```
export class SelectionOtherInputDescriptor {
    constructor(public selectionName: string, public otherKey: any, public otherInputElement: HTMLInputElement) { }
}
export class SelectionOtherInputHelper {
    selectionsWithOther: { [selectionKey: string]: SelectionOtherInputDescriptor; } = {};
    getAllSelectionOthers() {
        var things = $("[" + ATT_SELECTION_OTHER_FOR + "]");           
        for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {         
            var selectionName = $(things[i]).attr(ATT_SELECTION_OTHER_FOR);
            var desc = new SelectionOtherInputDescriptor(selectionName, 0, $(things[i]));
            this.selectionsWithOther[selectionName] = desc;
        };
    };
}
```

On the line

```
var desc = new SelectionOtherInputDescriptor(selectionName, 0, $(things[i]));
```

I get the compile error:

> Type 'JQuery' is missing property `setSelectionRange` from type
>   'HTMLInputElement'

Why does my own `SelectionOtherInputDescriptor` object require that the `HTMLInputElement` parameter require a `setSelectionRange` property when all I want to do with it is store it in an object in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(things[i])` returns a JQuery object, but your class wants an HTML element. Observe:

```
<input id="foo">
   ....
var x = $('#foo');
console.log(x); // 'JQuery'
console.log(x.get(0)); '<input id="foo">
```

You'll need to call `get` as shown. Since this is just going to be an HTMLInputElement, you'll also need to type-assert the result: `<HTMLInputElement>($(things[i]).get(0))`

Comment: Thanks. I suspected both, and tried before asking, but could not get the right syntax. `$(things[i])[0]` is what I would normally use though, to get from jQuery to DOM. I just couldn't get the type assertion right.